# Why condition in rowdatabound is getting failed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am trying to show a button where IsPublished is true, it works but except for the first row in the grid. Why? I have been trying it for so long but it doesn't work at all

```
protected void gvNITs_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("btnLinkDownload") as LinkButton;
        //if (lb != null)
        //    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lb);

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton Lbtn_change = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("Lbtn_change");
            HiddenField hdnPublishNITDate = e.Row.FindControl("hdnPublishedNITdate") as HiddenField;
            DateTime? dtPublishedNITDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnPublishNITDate.Value) == true ? null : (DateTime?)hdnPublishNITDate.Value.ToDate();
            HiddenField hdnIsPublishedNIT = e.Row.FindControl("hdnIsPublishedNITs") as HiddenField;
            bool IsPublished = hdnIsPublishedNIT.Value.ToBool();

            GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
            {
                if (IsPublished == true)
                {
                    Lbtn_change.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you have a nested loop. The `RowDataBound` event is triggered when a row is being added to the GridView. But in the RowDataBound event you loop all the rows in the GridView `foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)`

If you check `gv.Rows.Count` you will find that it is `0` in the first row because it has not yet been added to the GridView.

But you do not need that loop anyway since you already have access to `Lbtn_change`. So set the Visible property without the loop.